# Defining SYSLIB when using z/OS USS to compile/link

Tags: mainframe, zos

I'm using c++ (cxx) on z/OS USS to compile and link c programs. 
I'm getting errors from IEW (linker) that it can't access `SYSLIB`.

I'm assuming that this has to be an export e.g.

```
export _CXX_LSYSLIB="CEE.SCEELKEDX:CEE.SCEELKED:CBC.SCCNOBJ:SYS1.CSSLIB"
```

That was my best shot but still getting errors during linking.

```
ABEND S013-38 OCCURRED WHILE PROCESSING PARTITIONED DATA SET DDNAME SYSLIB.
```

Comment: Are you also receiving an IECnnn message? Perhaps [IEC141I](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieam700/ee141i.htm) ?

Comment: It's the weekend, I'm super busy, but just a thought: maybe you have to use the escape-to-standard-data-set naming convention? "//CEE.SCEELK??://CEE.SCEELKED:" etc.? (The ?? is because your first data set name is erroneous. Could that also be the issue?)

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to get the right setting of environment variables needed to properly link an application in USS on z/OS. The following command illustrates how this works:

```
> xlC -v  a.C
FSUM0000I  Utility(xlc)                      Level(D170323.1712)
exec: export(export,XL_CONFIG=/bin/../usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/etc/xlc.cfg:xlC,NULL)
exec: /usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/exe/ccndrvr(/usr/lpp/cbclib/xlc/exe/ccndrvr,./,./a.C,*.C,CXX,CMDOPTS(DEFINE(errno=(*__errno())),NOTEST,-qoe,-qargparse,-qexecops,-qflag=i,-qhalt=16,-qnodebug,-qnolsearch,-qredir,-qlocale=POSIX,-qlongname,-qmaxmem=*,-qmemory,-qnestinc=255,-qnoexpmac,-qnoexportall,-qnogonumber,-qtarget=le,-qnolibansi,-qlist=/dev/fd1,-qnolist,-qnomargins,-qnooffset,-qnosequence,-qnoshowinc,-qsource=/dev/fd1,-qnosource,-qnoxref,-qterminal,-qnooptimize,-qplist=host,-qspill=128,-qstart,-qnoipa,DEFINE(_OPEN_DEFAULT=1),-qdigraph,-qinfo=lan,-qtempinc=tempinc,-qnortti,-qlanglvl=extended:nolibext:nolonglong,-qnoattr,-qinlrpt=/dev/fd1,-qnoinlrpt,-qtmplparse=no,-qansialias),object(./a.o),NOPPONLY,NULL)
exec: export(export,STEPLIB=CBC.SCCNCMP:CEE.SCEERUN2:CEE.SCEERUN,NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_ACCEPTABLE_RC=4,NULL)
exec: /bin/cxx(/bin/cxx,-v,a.o,NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_ACCEPTABLE_RC=4,NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_PVERSION=0x42030000,NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_PSYSIX=CEE.SCEELIB(C128N):CBC.SCLBSID(IOSTREAM,COMPLEX),NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_PSYSLIB=CEE.SCEEOBJ:CEE.SCEECPP,NULL)
exec: export(export,_CXX_LSYSLIB=CEE.SCEELKEX:CEE.SCEELKED:CBC.SCCNOBJ:SYS1.CSSLIB,NULL)
FSUM0000I  Utility(c89)                      Level(D170323.1712)
//* cxx ------------------------------------------------------------------------
//LINKEDIT  EXEC  PGM=LINKEDIT,
//  PARM='AMODE=31,RMODE=ANY,TERM=YES,
//  DYNAM=DLL,ALIASES=NO,UPCASE=NO,
//  LIST=OFF,MAP=NO,XREF=NO,INFO=NO,MSGLEVEL=4,
//  REUS=RENT,EDIT=YES,AC=0,CALL=YES,CASE=MIXED'
//SYSLIB   DD  DSN='CEE.SCEELKEX',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//         DD  DSN='CEE.SCEELKED',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//         DD  DSN='CBC.SCCNOBJ',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//         DD  DSN='SYS1.CSSLIB',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//C8920    DD  UNIT=SYSALLDA,SPACE=(32000,(100,100)),
//             STORCLAS=,MGMTCLAS=,DATACLAS=,DSNTYPE=,
//             DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=3200)
//C8961    DD  DSN='CEE.SCEEOBJ',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//C8962    DD  DSN='CEE.SCEECPP',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//C8921    DD  DSN='CEE.SCEELIB(C128N)',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=NOTDIR
//C8922    DD  DSN='CBC.SCLBSID',DISP=SHR,DCB=DSORG=DIR
//SYSPRINT DD  PATH='/dev/fd1',
//             PATHOPTS=(ORDWR,OCREAT,OAPPEND),FILEDATA=TEXT,
//             PATHMODE=(SIROTH,SIRGRP,SIRUSR,SIWOTH,SIWGRP,SIWUSR)
//SYSTERM  DD  PATH='/dev/fd2',
//             PATHOPTS=(ORDWR,OCREAT,OAPPEND),FILEDATA=TEXT,
//             PATHMODE=(SIROTH,SIRGRP,SIRUSR,SIWOTH,SIWGRP,SIWUSR)
//SYSLMOD  DD  PATH='a.out',
//             PATHOPTS=(OWRONLY,OCREAT),
//             PATHMODE=(SIRWXO,SIRWXG,SIRWXU)
//SYSDEFSD DD  DUMMY,
//             DCB=(RECFM=F,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=80)
//SYSLIN   DD  *
  INCLUDE C8920
  INCLUDE './a.o'
  AUTOCALL C8961
  AUTOCALL C8962
  INCLUDE C8921
  INCLUDE C8922(IOSTREAM)
  INCLUDE C8922(COMPLEX)
/*
```

The output of this command shows what environment variables need to be exported and what data sets are defined for each. Naturally, one does not need to use the c89 utility directly, the same can be accomplished by using the xlc utility.

In your case a cxx command can be replaced with xlC -F:cxx or simply xlC as the xlC command is equivalent to cxx command that invokes the c89 utility. The bonus from using the xlc instead of the c89 utility is that you get to use shell friendly options which are specified using -q syntax and not -Wc,"..." syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, I think. Instead of:

```
_CXX_LSYSLIB="CEE.SCEELKEDX:CEE.SCEELKED:CBC.SCCNOBJ:SYS1.CSSLIB"
```

I think you want:

```
_CXX_LSYSLIB="CEE.SCEELKEX:CEE.SCEELKED:CBC.SCCNOBJ:SYS1.CSSLIB"
```

It's the extra 'D' that's killing you. Crappy error message I agree.